# How to distort an array of images - Processing

Tags: image-processing, processing

I am trying to distort a grid of images that are displayed randomly when the mouse is clicked.

I have the grid and the random when click.

I have accomplished the distorsion I want when I have only one image.

Now I have to merge both codes together, but I can't figure out how to do it when the PImage is an array.

Grid code:

```
PImage img[];
int nPics;

int w, h;

void loadImages(){
  for (int i = 0; i < nPics; i++) {
    img[i] = loadImage("img_"+ nf(int(random(0, 687)), 3) + ".jpg");
    imageMode(CORNERS);
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(1500, 500);
  nPics=27;
  img = new PImage[nPics];

  w=width/9;  
  h=height/3; 

  loadImages();
}

void mousePressed(){
  loadImages();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (int i=0; i<nPics; i=i+3) {  
    int col = i/3;
    for (int row=0; row<3; row++)
      image(img[i+row], col*w, row*h, (col+1)*w, (row+1)*h);
  }
}
```

Wave code:

```
PImage myImage;
float speed1 = .01;
float speed2 = 5;

void setup()
{
  size(1500,500);
  myImage = loadImage("img_001.jpg");
}

void draw()
{
  float distortion = map(mouseY, 0,500, 0, 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < myImage.width; ++i) {
    copy(myImage, i,0,1,height, i, (int) (sin((millis()+i*speed2)*speed1)*distortion),1,height);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the distortion to the entire canvas, you can just use `copy()` without the image parameter. This causes it to just copy from what is currently on the canvas.

You can use a very similar `for` loop to the one that's in your wave code, just omit the `myImage` parameter and let `i` go from 0 to `width` instead of `myImage.width`. Then you put it at the end of your `draw` block in the `grid` code:

```java
//global variables, include speed1 and speed2

void loadImages() {
  //as in grid code
}

void setup() {
  //as in grid code...
}

void draw() {
  //everything from grid code...

  float distortion = map(mouseY, 0,500, 0, 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    copy(i,0,1,height, //the rest...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really stuck with the image parameter, this is perfect!